# What is Supersymmetry (SuSy)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking

In particle physics, [supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) (often abbreviated SUSY) is a symmetry that relates elementary particles...etc.

- what is [symmetry breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_breaking)?
- What is supersymmetry (SUSY)?
- What is [spontaneous symmetry breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking)?

Comment: What exactly do you not like in the wiki articles and the references given there?

Comment: Each of those terms have a rather technical meaning. To explain them usually takes several lectures each, at least. That you ask about them in one question indicates that you have no, or little prior knowledge. I think you should at least indicate why you are interested in those questions.

Comment: I suggest reading http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28880/supersymmetry-in-quantum-mechanics answer to get you started

Comment: I would suggest splitting this into 3 separate questions, or at least breaking the symmetry breaking questions into a separate post. As it stands the post is not focused enough.

Answer (score 2):

SUSY is a symmetry that mixes fermions and bosons . It states that for each a fermion , there is a boson and for each a boson there is a fermion. As an example , For the graviton , there is a fermion called the gravitino .