# Mathematical concept of supersymmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, soft-question, supersymmetry

I wish to study supersymmetry in field theory(sometime in december). However, I am quite not sure what is needed for its study. In supersymmetry, I just want to get the mathematical idea, such as its algebra. I will finish a course in QM this semester. I have studied some lie algebra (Cahn, Georgi). I also have some knowledge about classical field theory such as E-L equations, yang-mills theory, gauge invariance, symmetry breaking, higgs mechanism which I acquired through the study of solitons. I DONT HAVE ANY KNOWLEDGE OF QUANTUM FIELD THEORY. Is this knowledge enough to study supersymmetry? What exactly in supersymmetry can I hope to learn in addition to the mathematics? WOuld it be possible for me to apply it to the standard model?

Hope this will not be closed as too specific.  I am looking for brief information on what exactly can one study in supersymmetry and its prerequisites.

Comment: I find it hard to see what you're exactly asking about. To learn SUSY, it's of course enough to know other aspects of quantum field theories, but SUSY is still new. If you only care about the Lie (super)algebra, it's given by several trivial lines. It's more interesting what it predicts in physics and how it leads to cancellations etc. Yes, SUSY may be added to the Standard Model, the minimal model gotten in this way is MSSM, the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model. But there are many other interesting supersymmetric theories.

Comment: @LubošMotl
OK. To be more precise. How much can I read about Supersymmetry with no knowledge of Quantum Field theory?

Comment: You might want to read *Supersymmetry for Mathematicians: An Introduction* by Varadarajan...

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac If you insist about it, thanks to wikipedia you can learn from this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetric_quantum_mechanics).

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend a study in QFT before going on to study SUSY. QFT has many quirks that make supersymmetry a very interesting expansion of the regular framework. You'd miss out on all that as you just had to believe the facts presented w/o following the thought that lead to the results in detail.

On the Mathematical level you will need Grassmann numbers and their calculus, however, most books on SUSY include a chapter introducing the neccessary concepts.