# Mathematical Physics SUSY QM Resource Recommendation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry

I want to study SUSY QM. I found some excellent physically motivated articles on Arxiv. Despite, I am especially interested in the mathematical structure behind SUSY QM.
Does anybody know whether there is a particularly good reference to start studying SUSY QM from a rigorous mathematical point of view. The reference should cover  Spectral analysis and a wide range of all the algebraic properties concerned with the topic.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28880/2451

Answer (score 2):

Prof. Arai Asao published  monographs that include  mathematically rigorous treatment of SUSY which  seem to be your posted subject.
 However those are written in Japanese. 
 Arai  published several research  papers on which some parts of those 
 monographs are based.
 I think these journal papers can be used for  pedagogic purposes if you have some familiarity with functional analysis.

Arai, Asao
On self-adjointness of Dirac operators in boson-fermion Fock spaces.
Hokkaido Math. J.  23  (1994),  no. 2, 319–353.
It is available from 
http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hokmj/1381412696

Arai, Asao(J-HOKK)
A general class of infinite-dimensional Dirac operators and path integral representation of their index. 
J. Funct. Anal.  105  (1992),  no. 2, 342–408.

The Dirac Equation (Texts and Monographs in Physics)
 by Prof.Bernd Thaller  seems to  include some relevant information,
 though its title is not SUSY itself.